# How to make an camera icon to only click photo not upload using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a camera icon using that i am only wanted to click photo not upload photo and i am able to create a camera icon and when i am clicking on that it shows choose file which i don't want to add in this here is my tried code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@7.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.css"
    />
    <script
      defer
      src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@7.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="material-icons" id="camera"> camera_alt </span>
  </body>
  <script>
    const camera = document.getElementById("camera");
    camera.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("camera is clicked");
      const input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.type = "file";
      camera.appendChild(input);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: If im understanding this correctly, you want to select a file when you click on the camera icon without showing the input element itself?

Comment: no i don't want to select file i want to just open the camera and i also don't want to remove the browse file option

Comment: On which platform you are trying to use this? I mean in browser or for hybrid app development.

Comment: on hybrid app development